# How should I handle this exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, error-handling, plaid

We're integrating Plaid in our app. Plaid basically lets the user login with their bank's credentials and in our app we're able to access the user's financial data provided by Plaid.

We expect the user to login with a student loan account. However, if they login with an account different than student loan account Plaid throws an exception when we try to access Plaid's product "liabilities".

It's our job to inform the user to use a student loan account. However, there's the chance that a student tries to login with a different account. In this case we have to handle the following exception:

`Plaid::ItemError {error_code: "PRODUCTS_NOT_SUPPORTED"}`

The request is made via Ajax from the client. On success the client redirects to the dashboard (`window.location.replace(/dashboard?message="+data.message+"&status="+data.status)`).

What should I return when Plaid raises the exception? I'm sending now a 500 (Internal Server Error) with a message, but the client is picking up this as a 'success'.  When does $.ajax interpret that there has been an error? What cases should be treated there?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `$` jQuery or Rails in this context? Not that it really matters though as both should NOT treat a 500 as a success.

Answer (score 0):

`403 Access Denied` seems like the appropriate response code to me.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403